# Spring kafka listener :Trying to print RECORD_METADATA as part of kafka listener

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to access various KafkaHeaders properties in my spring kafka  listener:

Here is my code for getting the KafkaListenerContainerFactory
:

```
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListener<String,GenericRecord>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties){

final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,GenericRecord> factory=new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new BatchLoggingErrorHandler());
factory.setBatchListener(true);
return factory;



}
```

**My listener code:**

```
@KafkaListener(topic="testTopic",groupId="testGroupId"){

public void consumeNotification(@Payload Request request, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA) RecordMetadata recordMetaData){

}



But I am getting exception in my Listener:

Missing header 'kafka_recordMetadata'  for method parameterType[class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata]
```

For all header properties, I am getting this error...Is it something to do with the producer?

All the properties in KafkaHeaders are creating issues for me. Everything is throwing  **MissingHeader error.**

Comment: How does it work if you don’t use batch listener option?

Comment: @Artem Bilan ,,I tried that also ..Set the error handler to seektoerrorHandler. and batchlistener to false..then also same error.

Answer (score 1):

See docs for supported headers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#consumer-record-metadata.

The `KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA` was never there. More over the `RecordMetadata` is a produce side object: `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata`.

Therefore it is not clear what drives you to do whatever you have in your code so far...

Comment: Wrong type - scroll down from Artem's link. `>Starting with version 2.5, instead of using discrete headers, you can receive record metadata in a ConsumerRecordMetadata parameter.` Use 

`@KafkaListener(...)
public void listen(String str, ConsumerRecordMetadata meta) {
    ...
}` Or `@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA) ConsumerRecordMetadata meta`.